# jQuery click: The function is running before I click the button. The code which is to be executed is already wrapped inside a function in click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The function inside `$('#btnPrint').click()` is running as soon as the page is loading. I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnPrint').click(function () {
        if ($("#txtsomething").val().length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                data: {
                     a: "10232",
                     b: qty,
                     c: $("#txtsomething2").val(),
                    d : $("#txtsomething3").val(),
                    e : sum
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) { }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this is inside `$(document).ready()` function. 
The print button is:

```
<input class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnPrint" tabindex="15" value="PrintIt" />
```

I am working on Visual Studio and I put breakpoints. The execution stops at the breakpoint on url: `@Url.Action()` method, which means it is entering the Ajax bracket without clicking.
What is going wrong here? I want the function to execute only when I click the PrintIt button.

Edit: I tried `console.log("Button clicked")`. It was getting printed only after I clicked the button. So, the event must be firing off only after I click the button. In that case, how can I access my controller methods?

Comment: Probably this: `$('document').ready(function{` ... should be `$('document').ready(function(){`

Comment: I am sorry, it is.

Comment: @Shady45 - It really shouldn't be either. As of jQuery v3, it should be `$(function() { });`, see http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Comment: That click handler definitely **is not** running without the click event. I think the breakpoint you're seeing get hit is *server-side* where you're filling in the URL in the JavaScript code, not *client-side*.

Comment: I tried `console.log("Button clicked")`, and it was getting printed only when I clicked the button. So, I think you are right, T.J. How can access I the controller method, then?

Comment: @Shady45 - I'm afraid ASP.Net MVC isn't my area of expertise. :-)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.